Marketing Cloud export multiple csv files into one zip file
I have 3 data extension that I would like to export into SFTP individually as csv, and then combine them into one zip file. I get exhausted of researching this and thought I ask experts here to help.  This is not one-time thing, but daily load. Here is how data is pulled:
Automation Studio:

SQL activity run daily for each data extension update (overwrite)
Data Extract Activity  > Extract Type > Data Extension Extract File
Transfer Activity > File Action > Move a File From Safehouse

I can see the .csv files in the SFTP.  Not sure how to zip them.  While 3 DEs are not a lot, but we may have more of these data feeds created for SFTP export and downloaded by our external CRM
Thanks,
Araarso

Demonstraing the functionality by

zipping  SourceDE_A and SourceDE_B to single zip file SourceDEs.zip




Instruction
Helper Screenshot




1. Create Data Extension Extract activity
 


2. Create File Transfer activity



3. Create ZIP Data Extract activity
 


4. Your automation should like something like this



5. You would see the ZIP in FTE once you run.





Make sure adjust other settings like, File location, FileNaming, using * (asterisk), Delete file option etc.

